# Null Pointer exeption On Startup

Tags: jetty, jax-rs, osgi, middleware, equinox

I try to fix this error that is appear in my project from day 0 that I receive an uncompleted project to complete it. In the master developer environment the project runs fine with the same settings and configuration. 
But in my working environment work, but printout extra this: `Error task.call(): java.lang.NullPointerException`, for every bundle that is connected in the middle-ware. 
All working fine except this error, so I suppose that there is somewhere a hidden trick that will fix it.
Thanks in advance!

```
Error task.call(): java.lang.NullPointerException
Error task.call(): java.lang.NullPointerException
Middleware Started!
e
bundleresource://8.fwk772779514/gosh_profile:20.9: RuntimeException: Command name evaluates to null: $exception
osgi> exit
Really want to stop Equinox? (y/n; default=y)
```

Comment: Do you have any better logs?  There's not much to work with here.

Comment: With the e command I get this errors only nothing more , and for this reason i get confused ? Is there any other command that i can get more explanation rather than e?

Comment: print only this as error : bundleresource://8.fwk772779514/gosh_profile:20.9: RuntimeException: Command name evaluates to null: $exception

Comment: You need to find the code where the NullPointerException is logged, and make sure it prints the full stack trace. Without this information it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: Ok ! I will try to debug it and see what is going on

Comment: I keep trying to find it with no luck . I hope that is something very clear but i can't find it out.

Comment: It takes me more that i thought to find out that eclipse mars can't activate some plugins that is eclipse Kepler version plugins and leave it in resolve state. I work using p2 repo. I beleve that I must change the required versions in the dependencies of this plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of time, building my own p2 repo and adding only the absolutely required plugins on its latest versions, fortunately fix that horrible issue! The previous repo had a lot of plugins that I didn't actually use it. Some of that plugins was outdated in the older repo and seem that it was not compatible with each other.